# MSSQL Stored Procedure Insert Arabic

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode

I'm working in a existing MS SQL database with Collation as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. The target column data type has been updated to NVARCHAR(MAX) and set collation to Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS. Using the stored procedure to insert/update  row the NVARCHAR(MAX) data type has been setup. The stored procedure is saving but the data is not in the correct format.

MS SQL MODIFY TARGET COLUMN

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER  COLUMN cLineNotes nvarchar(max) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS
```

MS SQL STORED PROCEDURE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProcedure
   ... --3 more lines here
   @pcLineNotes nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   ... -- more lines here
   INSERT INTO myTable (cLineNotes ) VALUES (@pcLineNotes )
   ... -- more lines here
END
```

PHP Connection Info Using UTF-8

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => $this->db_name, "UID" => $this->db_user, "PWD" => $this->db_pwd , "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
```

PHP Stored Procedure  Call

```
   $query = "{CALL  spMyProcedure( ?,?,?,?  )}"; 

   $params = array(
          array($param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,),
          array(&$param2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
          array(&$param3, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
          array(&$cLineNotes, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
   );
```

Sample cLineNotes value is اختبار يونيكود and stored value in database ط§ط®طھط¨ط§ط± ظٹظˆظ†ظٹظƒظˆط¯

Comment: Your PHP code says your using UTF-8 but your database is in ANSI/USC-2 (depending on if the datatype is a `varchar`/`nvarchar`); UTF-8 <> ANSI/USC-2. Your PHP will pass a `varchar` value, thinking SQL Server is in a UTF8 collation (which it isn't) and so the data is immediately lost as it is resolved as an ANSI value. If you want to use UTF-8 then use UTF-8 the *whole way through*, with both your database and column collated in UTF-8.

Comment: You probably need to specify the datatype of the SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_ for your parameters so it doesn't become VARCHAR

Comment: @ThomA Make sense. After clearing the UTF-8 from connection I get the same result.

@siggemannen Thought so  but I get the same result  with  ` array(&$cLineNotes, null,null,   SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR)`

Comment: @Zhorov the value is pickup from POST method.  Correct the charset UTF-8 was specified in header file.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'اختبار يونيكود'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1256')` returns `'ط§ط®طھط¨ط§ط± ظٹظˆظ†ظٹظƒظˆط¯'`. Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), see more at 
[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/).

Comment: The garbled data seems to me like you're trying to insert a UTF-8 byte stream into a UCS-2 field (bearing in mind that the ungarbled data is right-to-left). Have you tried using a length specifier in your params array instead? i.e.: `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR(50)` for an `NVARCHAR(50)` column/parameter, or `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR(max)` for `NVARCHAR(max)`? Ref: [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.constants.php)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Correct and result is the same.  Tried  also SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING('UTF-8') .

Suprisingly the value of cLineNotes when print_r() is in correct format.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. In PHP if I `$cLineNotes = "اختبار يونيكود";` and `echo $cLineNotes;` and `echo bin2hex($cLineNotes);` I get `اختبار يونيكود` and `d8a7d8aed8aad8a8d8a7d8b120d98ad988d986d98ad983d988d8af` which shows UTF-8 encoding in memory. From SQL Server if I `SELECT cLineNotes, CONVERT(varchar(max), CAST(cLineNotes AS varbinary(max)), 2) AS [Binary] FROM myTable` I get `اختبار يونيكود` and `27062E062A0628062706310620004A06480646064A06430648062F06` which shows that it's correctly storing UCS-2 encoding in the table. Perhaps the data posted to your PHP page is broken?